# COMO ESTENDER O BACKGROUND CINZA TRANSPARENTE DO MODAL POR COMPLETO?

Tags: html, css, modal

Estou com uma duvida sobre modal que está arrebentando minha cabeça. eu segui um tutorial do inicio ao fim pra fazer um modal pro meu prototipo de portfólio mas por alguma razão mesmo tudo estando nos conformes o background rgb cinza transparente nao cobre a tela toda. eu ja mechi em tudo que é coisa e nada mudou se alguem achar o erro por favor me diga

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>portifolio 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style3.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maxium-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
    <!-- barra de navegação -->
    <header>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="logo"><img src=""></div>
            <div class="menu"> <!-- menu --> 
                <a class="trigger" onclick="showModal()">Sobre</a>
                <a href="">Projetos Gráficos</a>
                <a href="">Contatos</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- barra de navegação fim -->
    <main>
        <div class="conteudo-sobre">
            <img src="Imagens2/image7.png">
            <div class="texto-sobre">
                <h1>JOÃO ROBERTO PESSOA NETO</h1>
                <h4>Designer Gráfico e Analista de Sistemas</h4>
                <div class="social-media">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jo%C3%A3o-roberto-pessoa-neto-161ba6214" target="_blank">Linkedin</a>
                    <a href="#">GithHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="modal" id="modal">
            <div class="modal-content sobre-mim">
                <span class="close-button" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
                <h5>Sobre Mim</h5>
                <p>Meu nome é João Roberto Pessoa Neto sou formado em design gráfico pela unibratec e estou cursando análise e desenvolvimento de sistemas na FICR.</p>
                <p>Fiz muitos trabalhos freelance para diversas pessoas, tanto dentro do país quanto fora, como: banners, cards, etc. Sei usar muito bem o Photoshop e já fiz diversos projetos de marketing etc em equipe com colegas da faculdade.</p>
                <ul>UNIVERSIDADE UNIBRATEC
                    Graduação em design gráfico em 2019
                    <li>- Formado no top 5% da turma</li>
                    <li>- Orador da turma</li> </ul>
                    <ul> FACULDADE CATÓLICA IMACULADA DO RECIFE (FICR)
                    Graduação em Análise e desenvolvimento de sistemas
                    <li>- Previsão de formatura em 20XX.2 </li>
                    <li>- Um dos melhores da turma </li> </ul>
                
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="java/app2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}
header
{
  padding: 20px; 
}
.center
{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 2000px;
}
.menu
{
  padding-top: 20px;
  width:95%;    
  text-align: right;
}
.menu a
{
  color: #00e5ff ;
  font-family: LEMON MILK;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu a:hover
{
 background: #eeff41; 
}
.conteudo-sobre 
{
  
}
.conteudo-sobre img 
{
  position: absolute; 
  margin-top: 40px;   
  margin-left: 1200px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;

}
.texto-sobre
{
 font-family: cocogoose;
 color: #00e5ff ;
 padding-top: 190px;
 padding-left: 50px;
}

.texto-sobre h4
{
 font-family: LEMON MILK;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #00e5ff;
 padding-left: 95px;
}
.social-media
{
  margin-left: 270px;
  margin-top: 30px;  
  display: flex;
}

.social-media a
{   
  color: #00e5ff ;
  font-family: LEMON MILK;
  margin-right: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 170px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #00e5ff;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}
.social-media a:hover
{
  background: #eeff41; 
}

.modal
{
position: fixed;
padding: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center; 
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
transform: scale(1.1); 
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden; 
transition: visibility 0.26s ease-in-out, transform 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.sobre-mim
{
  background-color: white; 
  border-radius: 0.5rem ;
}
.close-button
{
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 24px; 
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;  
  line-height: 24px; 

}
.close-button:hover
{
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
.show-modal
{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
```

```js
function showModal() {
        var element = document.getElementById("modal");
        element.classList.add("show-modal");
    }

    function closeModal() {
        var element = document.getElementById("modal");
        element.classList.remove("show-modal");
    }
```

[image: exemplo do que acontece]

Comment: A solução  é a Div que abre com o modal ter position Fixed e height e width de 100%. Mas coloce height de 100% tb no body e no html

Comment: eu fiz isso e continua a mesma coisa coloquei no body :position: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; no css html a mesma coisa e no main que tava a modal a mesma coisa. a div da modal ja possue essas tags

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O CSS padrão do Materialize, limita a altura do `.modal` para 70%, então reverta isso colocando `max-height: initial;` no estilo do `.modal`. Veja o código CSS completo abaixo:

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}
header
{
  padding: 20px; 
}
.center
{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 2000px;
}
.menu
{
  padding-top: 20px;
  width:95%;    
  text-align: right;
}
.menu a
{
  color: #00e5ff ;
  font-family: LEMON MILK;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu a:hover
{
 background: #eeff41; 
}
.conteudo-sobre 
{
  
}
.conteudo-sobre img 
{
  position: absolute; 
  margin-top: 40px;   
  margin-left: 1200px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;

}
.texto-sobre
{
 font-family: cocogoose;
 color: #00e5ff ;
 padding-top: 190px;
 padding-left: 50px;
}

.texto-sobre h4
{
 font-family: LEMON MILK;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #00e5ff;
 padding-left: 95px;
}
.social-media
{
  margin-left: 270px;
  margin-top: 30px;  
  display: flex;
}

.social-media a
{   
  color: #00e5ff ;
  font-family: LEMON MILK;
  margin-right: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 170px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #00e5ff;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}
.social-media a:hover
{
  background: #eeff41; 
}

.modal
{
position: fixed;
padding: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-height: initial; /* COLOQUE ISSO AQUI */
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center; 
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
transform: scale(1.1); 
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden; 
transition: visibility 0.26s ease-in-out, transform 0.25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.sobre-mim
{
  background-color: white; 
  border-radius: 0.5rem ;
}
.close-button
{
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 24px; 
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;  
  line-height: 24px; 

}
.close-button:hover
{
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
.show-modal
{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
```